# How to wrap an array of elements in an element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using this code, I get an array of list-items:

```
var column = this.children().slice(0, columnLength).remove()
```

I wish to wrap them in a ul tag so I can later apply them like this:

```
this.html(filler);
```

I would expect this to work.

```
filler = filler.add(column.wrapAll('<ul />'))
```

Full code:

```
jQuery.fn.splitList = function(num) {
    var columnLength = Math.ceil(this.children().length/num), filler = $j();
    while(this.children().length > 0){
      var column = this.children().slice(0, columnLength).remove()
      filler = filler.add(column.wrapAll('<ul />'))
      console.log(filler);
    }
    this.html(filler);
};
```

Comment: They would need to be LIs to be valid HTML if you wrap them in a UL. Wrapping them again makes no sense. Can you show sample HTML?

Comment: yes, they are, (list items, as I write)

Comment: Are you able to provide sample HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for your requirements:

```
filler = filler.add($("<ul></ul>").append(column));
```

I assume `column` is an `Array` of LI's.

Comment: Also, `wrapAll()` returns the original jQuery object, not a new one containing the wrapped elements. If you prefer to use `wrapAll()`, you may do the following:

`filler = filler.add(column.wrapAll('<ul />').parent())`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reference the newly wrapped-around parent UL in your add:

```
filler = filler.add(column.wrapAll('<ul />').parent());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/g5symcvy/